# how to handle pagination of a dynamic table in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

I have a table which stores user's favorites:

When user `X` marked an item `Y` as his favourites, a new record will be added to this table:

| id | user_id | item_id | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | X | Y | true |

When user `X` canceled his favorite on item `Y`, the `is_active` field will be set to `false`

| id | user_id | item_id | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | X | Y | false |

When user X **re-favorite** item Y, the `is_active` field will be set to true. Actually this is done by django `create_or_update()` method.

So the table is like:

| id | user_id | item_id | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 201 | true |
| 2 | 1001 | 202 | true |
| 3 | 1001 | 203 | true |
| 4 | 1001 | 204 | true |
| 5 | 1001 | 205 | true |
| 6 | 1001 | 206 | false |
| 7 | 1002 | 201 | true |
| 8 | 1002 | 202 | true |
| 9 | 1003 | 201 | true |

When user 1001 requests his favorites list, the queryset will be:

```
queryset = Favorite.Objects.filter(user=1001, is_active=true)
```

the response will be (I only list the record id):

```json
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

if the pagination size is set to 2, user 1001 will get a response:

```json
{
next: ...?page=2,
previous: null,
data:[1, 2]
}
```

but if user 1001 canceled his favorite on item 202 now, then, when he requests his favorites list of page 2, he will get:

```json
{
next: ...?page=3,
previous: ...?page=1,
data:[4, 5]
}
```

**In this scenario, record id = 3 is lost.**

**How can I solve this problem? What is the best practice? What did I miss?**

I am not a professional programmer, any help is highly appreciated. You can change everything, such as the table structure or the queryset methods....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When item 202 canceled from favorites the query set will be [1,3,4,5]. So the 3 has been shifted to first page and now second page include 4,5.

you can decide the system of pagination based on your need.

In the real time data pagination cases which you have a lot of changes in your data like Twitter or instagram they use cruser based pagination instead of page based
You can see complete guide in this link:
https://www.sitepoint.com/paginating-real-time-data-cursor-based-pagination/
There are also other methods to implement pagination like Timestamp-based pagination.

You can consider see this link regarding pagination in restful API:
https://www.laurencegellert.com/2016/08/webservice-api-design-tips-correct-pagination-and-exposing-deleted-rows/

When a data item is removed from a paginated set in a RESTful API, it's sometimes considered good practice to keep the pagination stable and not dynamically change the table. But it is not always true.

It can be tricky to decide which system is good for your project and you should first describe your project and your needs

Comment: Hi, I have read your answer and links very carefully, then I go over the drf documentation, found that `rest_framework.pagination.CursorPagination` completely meet my requirement. 
see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination
Thank you very much!